# Date and time in 24 hours format

Tags: php, mysql, date, datetime, datetime-format

I have a date in this format `Fri, 15 Jan 2016 15:14:10 +0800`, and I want to display time like this `2016-01-15 15:14:10`.

What I tried is:

```
$test = 'Fri, 15 Jan 2016 15:14:10 +0800';
$t = date('Y-m-d G:i:s',strtotime($test));
echo $t;
```

But it is displaying date in this format: `2016-01-15 7:14:10`, it should be `2016-01-15 15:14:10`.

How can i do this?

Comment: What is the timezone setting on your server?

Answer (score 60, accepted):

Use [`H`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) instead:

```
$test = 'Fri, 15 Jan 2016 15:14:10 +0800';
$t = date('Y-m-d H:i:s',strtotime($test));
echo $t;
```

> **H**: 24-hour format of an hour with leading zeros   00 through 23

G should be the same, but without leading zeroes though. I suspect that your PHP is set to a different timezone than `+0800`. Can you confirm your timezone (`date_default_timezone_get()`)?

### EDIT

**OP confirmed that his timezone was set to UTC, in which case it maskes perfect sense that it shows 7 in the morning, as `date` uses PHPs default timezone.**

If you want to "inherit" the Timezone, while getting more flexibility, you should switch to [`DateTime`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php):

```
echo (new DateTime($test))->format("Y-m-d H:i:s");
```

Comment: `date_default_timezone_get()` displyas only UTC

Comment: i also tried `H` but no luck, displaying `2016-01-15 07:14:10`

Comment: That's why. You're inputting a date from a timezone that is 8 hours after UTC, in which case it makes perfectly sense that it corresponds to 7 in the morning at your local time.

Comment: So what i have to do now? How can i set ?

Comment: I didn't downvote, so I don't know. Probably because it appears like you didn't put that much effort into researching or consulting the PHP manual before you created a question here.

Answer (score 7):

https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_date.asp

#### Get a Date

The required format parameter of the date() function specifies how to format the date (or time).

Here are some characters that are commonly used for dates:

- d - Represents the day of the month (01 to 31)
- m - Represents a month (01 to 12)
- Y - Represents a year (in four digits)
- l (lowercase 'L') - Represents the day of the week

---

#### Get a Time

Here are some characters that are commonly used for times:

- H - 24-hour format of an hour (00 to 23)
- h - 12-hour format of an hour with leading zeros (01 to 12)
- i - Minutes with leading zeros (00 to 59)
- s - Seconds with leading zeros (00 to 59)
- a - Lowercase Ante meridiem and Post meridiem (am or pm)

---

https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.format.php

```
public DateTime::format ( string $format ) : string
```

---

```
<?php

    $datetime = new DateTime( "now", new DateTimeZone( "Europe/Bucharest" ) );

    echo $datetime->format( 'Y-m-d H:i:s' );
```