# How to get current datetime in codeigniter in 24 hour format

Tags: php, codeigniter

I'm trying to get the current datetime in codeigniter for my school project.
I made a sample function in controller for this which looks like this:

```
public function sample(){
        date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Manila');
        echo date('y-m-d h:i:s');
    }
```

however, i found out that this outputs `20-01-20 04:52:19` instead of `20-01-20 16:52:19`.
any idea how to fix this ? thanks .

Comment: Hint: `date('H')`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Date and time in 24 hours format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35127109/date-and-time-in-24-hours-format)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For 24 hour format of hours, use `y-m-d H:i:s` (uppercase **H** instead of lowercase h):

```
echo date('y-m-d H:i:s');   // Outputs: 20-01-20 17:04:00
```

As per the [docs](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php):

> **H** 24-hour format of an hour with leading zeros    00 through 23

For PM times you would get the 24 hour format, and for AM times, you would get the leading zero (eg: `05:04:13`).

If you prefer 24 format without leading zeros (16 for PM, 4 for AM), you can use **G**:

```
echo date('y-m-d G:i:s');   // Outputs for AM: 20-01-20 5:04:00 

// 12 hours later...
echo date('y-m-d G:i:s');   // Outputs for PM: 20-01-20 17:04:00
```

> **G**     24-hour format of an hour without leading zeros 0 through 23

Answer (score 2):

use **H** in stead of **h**

```
echo date('y-m-d H:i:s');
```

Answer (score 2):

Use **H** instead of **h** like below:

```
echo date("y-m-d H:i:s");
```

For more help, you may read the original doc of php https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php